# ASP.NET Session does not timeout on using ReportViewer Control

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, reportingservices-2005

We are using the ReportViewer control to display SSRS reports in our ASP.NET application. On pages where we use the ReportViewer control the session does not time out. The reason for this is the ReportViewer control emits a "setTimeOut" javascript function which reads the Session timeout value from the web.config and pings the server 1 minute before the configured value and keeps the session alive. For example, if the session timeout value is 5 minutes, the ReportViewer pings the server on the 4th minute. We used fidldler to verify this behavior. In addition, if we remove the ReportViewer control from the page, the sessions times out as expected.

We also tried using the ReportViewer control in a sample application and observed the same behaviour.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Regards,

Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with 2005, in the latest version Microsoft have added a property for the ReportViewer control to turn this off.

KeepSessionAlive="false"

Is upgrading an option?

Comment: Can you please let me know the version in which I will get this property? We are using SQL Server 2005 and VS 2005.

Comment: VS2010 which provides the ReportViewer 2010 control.